# How to change cycles in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe and I need to change the 3d column by the rule

1) if differ between i+1 row and i row of 2nd column > 1 then 3d column +1

I wrote a code using a cycle, but this code is working for eternity.

I wrote a code in pure python, but there must be a better way to do this in pandas.
So, How to rewrite my code in pandas to reduce time?

```
old_store_id = -1 
    for i in range(0,df_sort.shape[0]): 
        if (old_store_id != df_sort.iloc[i, 0]): 
            old_store_id = df_sort.iloc[i, 0] 
            continue 
        if (df_sort.iloc[i,1]-df_sort.iloc[i-1,1])>1: 
            df_sort.iloc[i,2] = df_sort.iloc[i-1,2]+1
        else:
            df_sort.iloc[i,2] = df_sort.iloc[i-1,2]
```

Before the code:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/nfmJHbA.png]

After the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['value'] = df.groupby('store_id')['period_id'].transform(lambda x: (x.diff()>1).cumsum()+1)
```

So we group by store_id, check when the diff between periods is greater than 1, then take the cumsum of the bool. We added 1 to make the counter start at 1 instead of 0.

Make sure that period_id is sorted correctly before using the above code, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Thx a lot for helping!) I am a newbie in this field) I used your code) But recenly I was sent another one)
data["new"] += \
            data.groupby("store_id")["period_id"].apply(lambda x: x.diff().gt(1).cumsum())
your code works 18 sec, this code 13 on my wooden PC)